# If a judge disallows "Direct" spells, can they still be played?

Tags: cheaty-mages

I'm a bit confused on what to do, here.  My judge specifically disallows "Direct" spells, and his Judgement type is "Eject".  I thought that his disallowing "Direct" spells would just prevent us from using them, but if that's the case, he'll never Eject someone for cheating with those spells because they couldn't be cast in the first place, right?

Per [the rulebook](http://www.alderac.com/images/2013/07/CM-Rulebook.pdf), page 6: "Special Effect: Any special effect of the judge.  Some have specific limitations for spells or unique judgements."

OK, that's fine. If we go to page 13 to the section on Judgement, it says "Eject: A more severe punishment, this fighter is ejected from the round.  The fighter's card is turned over, is removed from the round, and has no impact on the result for that round."

So are the players allowed to play "Direct" type spells on fighters, in order to get them forcefully ejected?  Or does the judge's disallowing of those spells mean that they can't be played at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off a cursory glance through the rules:

## If a spell type is disallowed by a judge, it may not be used for its normal effect.

Using your example, given that Direct spells are disallowed, you would not be able to play Direct Spells while that Judge is active. So you wouldn't be able to get a fighter ejected by playing direct-type spells on them. Similarly, if you have a judge that disallows support spells, you can't Dimension Door them away as Dimension Door is a support spell and thus disallowed.

If a card is played that is disallowed by the current judge (excluding "Foul Play!" in round 3) or was played incorrectly, it is discarded and its effect ignored (see page 16, under Disallowed Use of Cards).

### All spells played on a fighter contribute to their mana count.

Looking at page 13 shows an example where the only spells cast were Enchant spells (immediately before judgement, all face-down cards played on fighters are turned face-up). The judge is Lawty, mana limit 10 and intervention of Dispel. The Orc only has a Might enchantment applied, which places his mana at 4, well below the limit. The skeleton, though, has both Might and Giant Growth, which gives him 14 mana - over the limit. So the skeleton would be dispelled due to Lawty's intervention. If Lawty's intervention type were Eject instead, the skeleton would've been ejected.